# How long does it take to completely lick the door?

Tags: achievements, saints-row-iv

In Saints Row IV, there is this achievement:

> [image: Achievement Icon]
> **Minty Fresh**
> Lick the candy cane barricade all the way through in 'The Fight Before Christmas'.

[image]

Which requires you to lick down the candy cane door (as in press E and watching a "licking" animation many times) instead of going to the waypoints to disable the mechanical reindeers instead to eventually enter the factory through the wrapping area, in the mission "The Fight Before Christmas" in the "How the Saints Saved Christmas" DLC.

---

I was wondering:

### How long (in terms of time^ or times E is pressed) does it take to lick down the door?

I can't really time it as I am unable to keep a constant (more than 20FPS) framerate, and I forgot to count.

^Obviously while on a stable framerate...
EDIT: I guess 100 times.

Comment: [Let's find out. 1... 2... 3. It takes 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6rHeD5x2tI#?t=37s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mShXvcFww9Q) (now deleted) does it in a little more than 4 minutes, though I didn't watch it myself in detail so I'm not sure if there are time skips.

Also note the following (spoiler):

> Even after licking enough to cause the achievement to pop, you still need to go to the stables rather than through the door anyway, because "Oh, it's locked."

Comment: I knew that. (I just wanted to see how much time I needed to waste to get the achievement) | *In response to the hidden spoiler*

Comment: Hi Margaret, it appears the video has gone down so I have inlined the link for the time being. If you have a new video you wish to reference, please [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/202291/edit) your answer :)